# Submodules of direct sums of Verma modules for the Virasoro algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, mp.mathematical-physics, virasoro-algebra

Let $M_1=M(c, h_1)$, $M_2 = M(c, h_2)$ be two Verma modules for the Virasoro algebra. Let $N$ be a submodule of the direct sum $M_1 \oplus M_2$. I am wondering if there is any classification results for $N$. In particular, is N necessarily generated by singular vectors? Or is there other possibilities? Any comments will be appreciated.